# Incorrectly writing files using scanf() in C

Tags: c, file-io, printf, scanf

I'm having an issue writing a command line program to use a text file as input parameters before writing a new file after calculations. My current program looks like this:

```
  /* midi2hzf.c */

/*  Converts midi information files in the format midiNote - midiVelocity - duration(msecs) 
    into a frequency information file formatted frequency - ampFactor - duration(msecs)     */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float Hz, ampFat;
int midi, velo, durMidi, durHz;

float calHz(float Hz, int midi){
    Hz = pow(2, ((midi-69)/12))*440;
    return Hz;
    }

float calAmp(float ampFat, int velo){
    if (velo >= 0 && velo <= 127){
        ampFat = velo/127;
        return ampFat;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE *midiFile;
    midiFile = fopen("testmidi.txt", "r");

    FILE *hzFile;
    hzFile = fopen("testhz.txt", "w");

    if(midiFile==NULL||hzFile==NULL){
        printf("File error\n");
        return 1;
    }else{
        while(!feof(midiFile)){
            fscanf(midiFile, "%d%d%d", &midi,&velo,&durMidi);
            durMidi = durHz;
            calHz(Hz, midi);
            calAmp(ampFat, velo);
            fprintf(hzFile, "%f\t%f\t%d\n", Hz, ampFat, durHz);
            printf("%f\t%f\t%d\n", Hz, ampFat, durHz);
        }
    }

    fclose(hzFile);
    fclose(midiFile);}
```

Everytime I run the program, the output file contains "0.0000    0.0000    0", which is obviously not the desired output. As far as I can see, my functions are called correctly and all of the code makes sense, although the output is consistently wrong.

Comment: Check return value of `fscanf`. Try to debug your code.

Comment: How would I go about checking the return of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of errors in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Functions don't need an input for their output value.
float calHz(int midi){
    return pow(2, (midi - 69) / 12) * 440;
}

float calAmp(int velo){
    if (velo >= 0 && velo <= 127){
        return velo / 127.0;  // need to divide by floating point value
                              // so we don't just get integer division
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    // Variables should be declared locally.
    float Hz, ampFat;
    int midi, velo, durMidi, durHz;

    FILE *midiFile = fopen("testmidi.txt", "r");
    FILE *hzFile = fopen("testhz.txt", "w");

    if(midiFile==NULL||hzFile==NULL){
        printf("File error\n");
        return 1;
    }else{
        // You need to test the return value of fscanf to control the loop.
        while(fscanf(midiFile, "%d%d%d", &midi, &velo, &durMidi) == 3){
            durHz = durMidi;        // you had this the other way around
            Hz = calHz(midi);       // need to assign return value to Hz
            ampFat = calAmp(velo);  // ditto for ampFat
            fprintf(hzFile, "%f\t%f\t%d\n", Hz, ampFat, durHz);
            printf("%f\t%f\t%d\n", Hz, ampFat, durHz);
        }
    }

    fclose(hzFile);
    fclose(midiFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my lecturer is blasting through all these different functions, but no ones actually pointed things out to me (like the issue with integer division) to help me write with good practices.